# PHP Imagick makes PNG file with every-time changing specific binaries - from same image file

Tags: php, png, imagick

I have a PNG file problem.

When I convert an image using PHP Imagick library, I get different binary set each time although I tried with same image file several times.

When I compared those 2 files, it turns out it has only several bytes are just different, while rest of bytes are exactly same, and those bytes offsets are all time same, too.

I am really not sure how come those bytes could be all time different (seems like it stores timestamp or what else there?)

Here is the binary of PNG file with high-lighted binaries, and someone help me to figure out what the heck this binaries are:

[image]

I also attach the png file:

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: On the line above the one you have highlighted is the start of the `tIME` chunk which should be the last modification time ([see specs here](https://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/#11tIME)). You may also find [this Unix SE question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/255252/create-the-same-png-with-imagemagick-2-times-binaries-differ) helpful.

Comment: @JoshH why is this only added in Linux OS? How can I exclude this chunk when to save PNG using Imagick (PHP) then?

Comment: Since the differing bytes are at a known offset every time is it an option to add a post processing step to zero out those bytes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PNG files are "chunked" meaning that they have different named sections that define different data. In the [PNG file format specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/), you can find information on the `tIME` chunk in a PNG file.

> The tIME chunk gives the time of the last image modification (not the
>   time of initial image creation).

Another thing to note from the specs is that the first letter is lowercase (`t`), which means that the chunk is not required. So, removing it completely should solve your problem.

I haven't used Imagick, but going through the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/imagick), it looks like it provides a way way to remove the `tIME` chunk from the created PNG file. The `setOption` method gives you more control over what Imagick does with the image ([list of available options](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#define)). The `png:exclude-chunk` option is probably what you are looking for.

This code is untested, as I do not have access to a server with the Imagick library at this time.

```
$im = new Imagick();
$im->setOption('png:exclude-chunk', 'tIME'); // comma separated list of chunks
```

Comment: thank you for providing 2 solutions, I did upvote for both of them, and accept this as this is working well!

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely due to the image's metadata? Namely the timestamp when the file was modified?

Looking at the line that comes before the highlighted one, I can see tIME in there, so it seems that this would be the case.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to remove `tIME` chunks from images that have already been created or if you do not have access to the Imagick library, I tested out some code that can remove the chunk from small-ish* PNG files.

PNG files have a [specific format](https://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/):

- PNG signature [8 Bytes]
- Chunk data - starts with IHDR and ends with IEND chunks with other chunks in between. Each chunk has the following:

  - Length [4 Bytes]
  - Type [4 Bytes]
  - Data [Length Bytes] (may be empty if length is 0)
  - CRC (Cyclic Redundancy Code) [4 Bytes]

Using this information, we can read through the chunks one by one to find the one we want to remove.

```
// read the PNG file's contents into a string
$str = file_get_contents('hD0aZ.png');

// how far into the string we are currently
$offset = 0;

// offset for the PNG signature (8 bytes)
$offset += 8;

// what we will replace in the original string once it is found
$timechunk = '';

while($offset < strlen($str)){
    // get the current chunk information
    list($length,$chunk,$name) = readchunk(substr($str,$offset));
    if($name == 'tIME'){
        $timechunk = $chunk;
        break;
    }
    // move to the next chunk
    $offset += $length;
}

header("Content-Type:image/png");
print str_replace($timechunk,'',$str);

function readchunk($str){
    $length = hexdec(bin2hex(substr($str,0,4)));
    // 4 bytes for length, 4 bytes for chunk name, 4 bytes for CRC = 12 bytes
    return array(
        12+$length,                 // total length of chunk
        substr($str,0,12+$length),  // full chunk data
        substr($str,4,4)            // chunk name
    );
}
```

*If your PNG file is too large and the `tIME` chunk isn't early enough in the string, you may end up with issues if your `$offset` tries to go over `PHP_INT_MAX`. I was, however, able to get this code to work on the image you provided in the question.